# How to improve a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I wrote the following batch file below in order to clean temp files and clear cache.

Problem is that when someone downloads this file he gets a notification that this file may harm his/her computer.

I wonder if there is any way to make this script safe so no alert message will pop up

```
@echo off
echo Clear Temporary Internet Files: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2
echo Clear Cookies: 
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8
echo Clear temp files
cd %temp%
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
echo Clear speexx files
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\digital publishing\cltlms
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
echo Clear java cache files
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\sun\java\Deployment\cache\*.*
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
echo Clear Mozilla firefox cache files and cookies
taskkill /im "firefox.exe"
set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"
for /d %%x in (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*) do del /q /s /f %%x\*sqlite
echo Clear Google chrome cache files and cookies
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache*.*
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *
```

Comment: No. The warning is due to the security settings on the machine that downloaded your file. You have no control over these settings.

Comment: Exactly as @david says; imagine if you could do that, wouldn't everyone writing malicious software do it too?

Answer (score 0):

There is a stream attached to files that come from unknown sources. So if copying it on a network remove the security stream from the source file. If the file is coming from an unknown source (ie the internet/email etc) remove the stream (which is what happens if the user clicks Don't Ask Again checkbox in that security dialog).

This what `dir /r` shows

```
 Directory of C:\Users\User\Desktop\ProcessExplorer
06/05/2015  01:38 PM         2,925,760 procexp.exe
                                    26 procexp.exe:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
               1 File(s)      2,925,760 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\User\Desktop\ProcessExplorer\FileWatcher
06/05/2015  01:38 PM             7,168 VB2Exe.exe
                                    26 VB2Exe.exe:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
06/05/2015  01:38 PM             7,168 vbs2exe.exe
                                    26 vbs2exe.exe:Zone.Identifier:$DATA
               2 File(s)         14,336 bytes
```

To delete trash the data

```
echo. > "vbs2exe.exe:Zone.Identifier:$DATA"
```

Asyou seem to be disk cleaning you may want to see my post here http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/how-do-you-fix-computer-when-the-c-drive-and-d/e36a6d4b-155f-4a83-9475-4dcb41d0467d